# Trying to remove duplicate info received from an xml file displayed on my html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, ajax

I am trying to delete the duplicate atrists that are displayed when I retrieve the info from this xml file using JQuery. How can I accomplish this?

Here is the js file:

```
$(function(){
$(window).load(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://imaginationeverywhere.info/djronlove/new_2.xml',
        dataType: 'xml',
        success: function(xml){
            $(xml).find("key:contains('Artist') + string").each(function(){
                var string1 = $(this).text();
                $('<p></p>').addClass('string1').html(string1).appendTo('#container');
            });
        }
    });
});
$('<div></div>').attr('id', 'container').appendTo('body');
});
```

Here is the html file:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>DJ Ron Love Music Catalog</title>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://imaginationeverywhere.info/jslib//dev/jquery-1.5.1.js'>
    </script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="http://imaginationeverywhere.info/djronlove/itunes.js">
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <!--<h3>Songs that currently in DJ Ron Love's Music Catalog</h3>-->
    <h3>Artist that DJ Ron Love currently has in roatation</h3>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one way you may want to try is by creating a master artist array, and then querying that before adding new artists. You can do this easily using jquerys "inArray" function.

```
var masterArray = new Array();
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://imaginationeverywhere.info/djronlove/new_2.xml',
    dataType: 'xml',
    success: function(xml){
        $(xml).find("key:contains('Artist') + string").each(function(){
            var string1 = $(this).text();
            if( jQuery.inArray(string1, masterArray) == -1 ){
                $('<p></p>').addClass('string1').html(string1).appendTo('#container');
                masterArray.push(string1);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Note: there may be more efficent ways to do this, but if you're just looking for something simple, that may work.